# Perform search on Android within the same activity

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I'm trying to integrate search in my app but I'm being blocked by one issue. My activity is declared like this and is located inside of TabActivity.

```
    <activity
        android:name="FileBrowserActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

As you can see its launchMode is set to singleTop. But when I invoke search, input the search query and press enter another instance of such activity is launched. No onNewIntent is being called! But in the launched activity each new search doesn't launch a new activity.

The desired behaviour is to stay within current activity. Basically that's how android launcher search works.

Answer (score 9):

You should rather use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` like described [in this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#LifeCycle).

Answer (score 1):

You could use android:noHistory http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist